# Why do UITableView actions only work on visible cells

Tags: ios, swift, didselectrowatindexpath, uitableview

I'm working with a UITableView which is a list of friends (I have 20 friends). I have, on top of those 20 friends cells, a unique cell in another section called "ALL FRIENDS" which allows me to select all my friends in one click.

When this "ALL FRIENDS" cell is selected, this code is called :

```
var index = 0
for friend in self.friendsList {
    var indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: index, inSection: 1)
    self.tableView.selectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.None)
    index += 1
}
```

Everything works fine for the visible cells. When a cell is selected the background color changes but **this only works for visible cells**.

Any ideas why ?

Answer (score 2):

Because `UITableView` is dynamically displayed and invisible cells are not there.

`UITableView` basically dequeues a cell that's about to disappear and appends it where you're scrolling. To select all of the cells, you have to do it differently:

1. You'll have to set a global variable to `true`, let's say `var allSelected = true`.
2. Then call `self.tableView.reloadData()`
3. Which will be reflected in `tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell` by doing `cell.selected = true`.

That will ensure that all of the future displayed cells will be selected as well.

Answer (score 0):

So Michal's answer is great, but I would like to give you an alternative: you can create that tableview without dequeuing and reusing cells, so the cells remain alive at all points.

You can do this by creating individual cells, and adding them to an array

```
var array = [UITableViewCell]
for friend in self.friendsList {
    var cell = UITableViewCell()
    // customize your cell however you want, or use custom nibs
    array.append(cell)
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
  return array[indexPath.row]
}
```

Comment: An alternative solution indeed. Have you tried using this with 100 cells, each having an image, though? Look in the debug navigator and inspect the memory usage graph. Interesting isn't it?

Comment: I know, and I know it's not recommended. But then again, I don't know what he want's to use it for. 20 cells is not that bad.

Comment: I do agree that for some very rare occasions - if you're absolutely sure the list won't exceed some small number - it can be a quick solution.